# How to filter data in odoo calendar?

Tags: odoo

i want to filter some data in standart odoo calendar. I need to dont show events, that is private for users, who dont participate that event, i can do this by adding new filter in views, like:

```
<filter string="new filter" name="dont_show_others_private_events" domain="['|', ('privacy','=','public'), '&amp;' ,('partner_ids.user_ids', 'in', [uid]), ('privacy', '=', 'private')]"/>
```

but problem is, that this filter is visible and any user can turn it off.

How can i do the same on server level, maybe in models.py file? or there is way to hide this filter but leave it active? i tried also white this filter in views:

```
<record id="action_calendar_event_type" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Meeting Types</field>
    <field name="res_model">calendar.event.type</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_calendar_event_type_tree"/>
    <field name="domain">['|', ('privacy','=','public'), '&amp;' ,('partner_ids.user_ids', 'in', [uid]), ('privacy', '=', 'private')]</field>
</record>
```

but is doesnt work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly you want this "filter" to always be active and users cannot disable it ?

If that is the case then add a new Record Rule and not a filter.
You can add the new entry in the xml under the Security folder.

And here is an example of the record rule:

```
<record id="private_events_filter" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Private events filter</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="calendar.event"/>
    <field name="domain_force">['|', ('privacy','=','public'), '&' ,('partner_ids.user_ids', 'in', [uid]), ('privacy', '=', 'private')]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_portal'))]"/>
</record>
```

Comment: i also find this way last night,
this works well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
<record id="calendar_event_rule_private_dont_show_others" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_calendar_event"/>
    <field name="name">Dont show other private ivents</field>
    <field name="domain_force">['|', ('privacy','=','public'), '&amp;' ,('partner_ids.user_ids', 'in', [user.id]), ('privacy', '=', 'private')]</field>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
</record>
```